# mod_pagespeed not deferring javascript

Tags: javascript, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am trying to defer my javascript loading according to Google's pagespeed analysis of my site. However they are complaining about the following:

```
http://www.example.com/pagespeed_static/js_defer.pbrP1whUgE.js
```

which is the code that is automatically generated by them. How can I defer this to load at the end?

In my pagespeed.conf file I have the following set:

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters defer_javascript
```

On an additional note, has anyone else noticed that Google Chrome's audit's complain about using adsense and recommend optimizing no optimizable code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completly sure but I think that to enable `defer_javascript` you have to change the `RewriteLevel` to `PassThrough` and manually enable the filters you want (this will override the `CoreFilters` that are enabled by default).

An example from the [official site](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/config_filters#enabling):

**Apache**:

```
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css,extend_cache,rewrite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css,rewrite_javascript
```

**Nginx**:

```
pagespeed RewriteLevel PassThrough;
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css,extend_cache,rewrite_images;
pagespeed EnableFilters rewrite_css,rewrite_javascript;
```